# regex return whole word match result

Tags: javascript

How do I match whole word?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to do a global search for "is" in a strisng.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Is Alvin this all there is sis?";
    var patt1 = /is|alvin/gi;
    var result = str.match(patt1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is expected ?

Comment: Write What you expected resulted clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `\b` word boundary pattern.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to do a global search for "is" in a strisng.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Is Alvin this all there is sis?";
    var patt1 = /\b(?:is|alvin)\b/gi;
    var result = str.match(patt1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```